# Rails passing parameters to pages and calling different methods based on them

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I continue with my newbie questions coming from PHP, there might be more than one question below, thanks for your patience.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a template (view) called search.html.erb where I want different methods to be called depending on user input, specifically get variables passed by a link in a previous page. So for exmample if users click on the "commas" link it would pass something like

```
search?type=commas
```

(I've substituted action for type because I understand 'action' is reserved in Rails for methods declared inside the Controller). The route file has this:

```
  match ':controller/:action/:type/'
```

Which is supposed to allow me to do "http://localhost:3000/actors/search/commas as a way to pass the 'commas' type?

Then the search page would call the showCommas method from the Actors Model:

```
def self.showCommas
    @commas = self.where("actor LIKE ?", "%,%,%")
end
```

If they clicked on "acute" it would pass

```
search?type=acute
```

And the page would call the acute method in the Actors Model.

Finally I also want them to be able to pass a search term and the search page would do a SQL query with that term using .find_by_sql.

This is trivial to implement in PHP, I just use a

```
if ($_GET[action] == 'commas') { ...
```

But how to do it in Rails? Problems I have:

If I create a method in the Actor controller for a search term:

```
def search(term)    
    Actor.find_by_sql([sql query here with '%#{term}%']) 
end
```

Rails will complain that I have too many arguments for a method in the controller. So I've moved all my methods to the Model (guessing this is the right way to do it then?)

Putting this into my search.html.erb page:

```
if type.nil?
    criteria = "No type specified"
elsif type == 'commas' 
    criteria = type
    @actors = Actor.showCommas
end
```

Gives me an error immediately about the type variable not being defined: undefined local variable or method `type'

So I've made a grand mess of things, but as great as Rails is, coming from PHP it's quite hard to wrap your head around the Rails way of doing things. I understand the primary philosophy of having a view with the same name as your action and Rails will call it, but I don't want to build one page for every query (or other little thing) I need to do. Furthermore, the books I've read don't seem to go into detail about this, so, again, thanks for your help and indulgence in asking multiple questions in one post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to fully answer this question as a little info is missing but hopefully this steers you in the right direction.
Your `search?type=commas` url will route to the actors controller where by the looks of it you have a search method. The type=commas will be accessible in the params hash (params[:type]).

In rails its best practice to move as much logic into the model as you can, so whereas coming from php it would feel natural to do something like this in you controller:

```
def search  
    if params[:type] 
        if params[:type] == "commas"
            ... search logic
        elsif
            ... other search logic
        end 
    end
end
```

In Rails the controller method using you naming convention would look more like this;

```
def search 
    @actors = Actor.search(params[:type])
end
```

Note the `params[:type]` to access your type url parameter. The way you had written it you had type as a controller method argument which is incorrect as controller methods do not have arguments.

And the model could look something like this;

```
def self.search(type)
    case type
    when "commas"
      Actor.where(:type => "commas")
    when "whatever"
      Actor.where(:type => "whatever")
    else
      Actor.all
    end
end
```

Your search method will obviously be much different but that is just and example of how to pass params from url right through to the model.

Comment: thanks a lot, I think I'm beginning to understand: you have a method in the Model, then another one in the Controller that calls that method in the model?

Comment: Also, markijbema says not to do it in the Model but to do in the controller so I can have the GET variables. Which one is preferred method?

Comment: This is working great! Thanks a lot. A couple of followup questions: 1. I've had to put this into my routes.rb page in order not to kill the default actions (like destroy): 
    `resources :actors`  
    `match ':controller/:action/:type/'`. (separated by a new line, but I can't replicate it here) Is this correct?

Comment: 2. How would I go about having the Destroy action return to the page from which it was called with the same parameters? Because I want to call it from this search page and would like it to return there with the same results after it kills that entry.

Comment: Great to hear its working well. To answer your first two comments, Yes thats correct you can have just have the controller which calls `Actor.where(...)` directly, however in a search method you will usually have so much other conditional logic that it makes more sense to move some of this into the model. As for your next two comments, Post these as new questions as you'll get much better answers and its impossible to put tidy examples in the comments due to formatting

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this in the model, do it in the controller. You automatically get the GET parameters (just like in PHP). It is in the params hash. You could for instance do a case on it:

```
def search
  case params[:type]
  when 'commas'
    search_with_commas
  when 'acute'
    search_with_acute
  ...
  else
    default_search
  end
end

private
  def search_with_commas
     ...
  end

  ...
```

of course, if you only need to modify the query, you can just get the query in the when and handle everything in one action.

Comment: thanks for the answer, you say not to do it in the Model but to do in the controller so I can have the GET variables. Below, adam says to do it in the model, which one would be the preferred method?

Comment: It's conventional wisdom to have 'fat models' and 'skinny controllers', and i agree. Logic should go into your models. Modellogic, that is. However, this logic relates to how your controller should behave. However, it would be good to write out the actual queries in the models, and have seperate methods for them, and then choose a method in the controller. But processing get parameters in the model tends to be not so good an idea...

Comment: ok, thanks. What about redirecting the result of a destroy action back to the page that called it, including the variables. This is so I can go back to the search page with the same terms I had before.

Comment: I got it: redirect_to(request.referer)

Comment: redirect_to :back should also work: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Redirecting/redirect_to